# "angular.js line 12502 > function" is automatically added multiple times

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to work with angular and its working perfectly with my $http, controller and views. But when I'm seeing firebug debugger, in scripts tab "angular.js line 12502 > function" is automatically added multiple times. Inside it is showing like:

```
s = eso(s, fe);
l = eso(l, fe);
if(s == null) return undefined;
s=eso(((l&&l.hasOwnProperty("getAssess"))?l:s).getAssess, fe);
return s;
```

version I'm using 
/**
 * @license AngularJS v1.3.6
 * (c) 2010-2014 Google, Inc. http://angularjs.org
 * License: MIT
please help what i'm doing wrong.

Snapshot:

*/[image]

Comment: This is not necessarily unusual behaviour. It's angular setting up your bindings. What you see is a function internally created by `$parse` that can then be used to safely get or set a value. Does every one in the list display exactly the same function?

Comment: @james: "getAssess" is one of function.

$scope.getAssess = function (catID) {}


everyone is for different function in my application.

Comment: if you run this function in your console, you can see how many bindings your angular app has - http://pastebin.com/bgrfscSJ

Comment: @james hi, i am also facing same thing, does there is any trick to remove it?

Answer (score 2):

Its not a scary thing. Its just visible in Mozilla's firebug.Let me tell you the reason behind this code.
AngularJs creating dynamic functions at runtime for the variables that storing information in objects. But this is happening on first run only. After that these methods works to collect information from s or l( means scope or local).

These line are changing with versions as

Angularjs v1.3.1 will show at line number 12283 as this code working here to create functions.

```
 /* jshint -W054 */
var evaledFnGetter = new Function('s', 'l', code); // s=scope, l=locals
/* jshint +W054 */
```

Angularjs v1.3.6 will show at line number 12502 as this line working

```
 /* jshint -W054 */
var evaledFnGetter = new Function('s', 'l','eso','fe' code); // s=scope, l=locals, eso=ensureSafeObject
/* jshint +W054 */
```

Angularjs v1.3.7 had some more work on this function as [Find here change sheet](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/c90ad96808be350526516626205c3a7d1da79024)

> a chain of field accessors should use a single getterFn

Keep updated by checking this [Change Sheet](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)